# How to solve a system of integral equation

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I am stuck on the following problem: given this set of integral equations:
$$\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_0)=k_1\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_1)$$
$$\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_0)=k_2\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_2)$$
$$...........................$$
$$\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_0)=k_N\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda S(\lambda)W(\lambda,T_N)$$
where $W(\lambda,T)$ is a known function, I need to find $S(\lambda)$.
Putting $\displaystyle S(\lambda)=\sum_{j=0}^Na_j\lambda^j$ can
the system of integral equations can be reduced to an algebraic equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your indexes don't seem to be right.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: sorry. Just corrected it.

Comment: Are the $k$'s given or unknown ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: $k$s known

Comment: Then you can rewrite all equations in the form $\int d\lambda S(\lambda)w_j(\lambda)=0$ which expresses orthogonality of $S$ with the $w_k(\lambda):=W(\lambda,T_0)-k_j\cdot W(\lambda,T_j)$. You can obtain suitable $S$ from an arbitrary function by a step of the Gram-Schmidt process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w_i(\lambda):=W(\lambda, T_0)-k_iW(\lambda,T_i)$, and $<f,g>:=\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_1}d\lambda f(\lambda)g(\lambda)$, which are scalars.

Then take any $F(\lambda)$ such that the integrals below are defined, and let

$$S(\lambda):=F(\lambda)+\sum_{i=1}^N a_iw_i(\lambda).$$

The given equations imply

$$<S,w_j>=<F,w_j>+\sum_{i=1}^N a_i<w_i,w_j>=0.$$

Unless the system is singular, you can solve for the $a_i$ and obtain $S$.